# why is my reading type blank?

Tags: c

well i coded this for some homework and i know it can be modified better and could use some more comments but this one error is killing me ...... wondering if its just me or something but could you tell me if the error happens to you to.

Error: Reading type doesn't have any data.

(you can just use these inputs for now since i haven't error check the program) 
Test variables :

```
2345
AA
20
30
40
50
60
10
R( supposed to be entered) but program skip
```

it is suppose to take a input for rea_type but skips it and proceeds to the other lines.

Here is the code:

```
  const float deposit  = 1500.00;
const unsigned multiplier =1;
const float rate_One = 6.350;
const float rate_Two = 14.520;
unsigned bill_Cycle = 0,
         no_Days = 0;
float bi_Exch_Rate = 0,
      ba_Exch_Rate = 0;
float cur_Read=0,
      prev_Read=0,
      cur_Usage=0,
      cur_Peri_Charg=0;
char c_Digit[20],
     premis_numb[20];
char rea_type;
/**Information to be collected from the user**/
      system("cls");
      printf("\nPlease enter the customer digits: ");
      scanf("%s",&c_Digit);
      printf("\nPlease enter Premise Number:");
      scanf("%s",&premis_numb);
      printf("\nPlease enter the Billing Cycle: ");
      scanf("%d",&bill_Cycle);
      printf("\nPlease enter the No. of Days: ");
      scanf("%d",&no_Days);
      printf("\nPlease enter the Billing Exchange Rate: ");
      scanf("%f",&bi_Exch_Rate);
      printf("\nPlease enter the Base Exchange Rate: ");
      scanf("%f",&ba_Exch_Rate);
      printf("\nPlease enter the Current Reading: ");
      scanf("%f",&cur_Read);
      printf("\nPlease enter the Previous Reading: ");
      scanf("%f",&prev_Read);
      printf("What is the Reading Type: ");
      scanf("%c",&rea_type);
       cur_Usage = cur_Read-prev_Read;
         if (cur_Usage<100)
         {
           cur_Peri_Charg = cur_Usage*rate_One;
         }
         else
         {
          cur_Peri_Charg = (((cur_Usage-100) * rate_One)+(cur_Usage*rate_Two));
         }
       strcat(premis_numb,c_Digit);/**Joins the Premis Number and the Customer digits together**/
 /**Information to be displayed showing user all input and calculations.**/
  system("cls");
 printf("\tStored constants for calculation of customer bill\n");
 printf("      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
 printf("       Customer Number:%s",premis_numb);
 printf("          Current Usage:%.2f \n",cur_Usage);
 printf("\n");
 printf("       Billing Cycle:%d\t\t       No of Days:%d\n",bill_Cycle,no_Days);
 printf("\n");
 printf("       Billing Exchange Rate:%.2f     Base Exchange Rate:%.2f\n",bi_Exch_Rate,ba_Exch_Rate);
 printf("\n");
 printf("       Deposit:%.2f\t\t       Multiplier:%d\n",deposit,multiplier);
 printf("\n");
 printf("       Rate 1:%.3f\t\t       Rate 2:%.3f\n",rate_One,rate_Two);
 printf("\n");
 printf("       Current Reading:%.2f\t       Previous Reading:%.2f\n",cur_Read,prev_Read);
 printf("\n");
 printf("       Current Usage Reading:%.2f    Reading Type:%c\n",cur_Peri_Charg,rea_type);
 printf("      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a string for `rea_type` as it will be more robust to bad input than a single char, i.e. change:

```
char rea_type;
```

to:

```
char rea_type[20];
```

and:

```
  scanf("%c",&rea_type);
```

to:

```
  scanf("%s", rea_type);
```

---

Also note that you should ideally change both:

```
  scanf("%s",&c_Digit);
```

and:

```
  scanf("%s",&premis_numb);
```

to:

```
  scanf("%s", c_Digit);
```

and:

```
  scanf("%s", premis_numb);
```

You don't need to take the address of a string, as it's already effectively a pointer. It doesn't matter in this particular case but it's a good habit to get into as when the strings really are pointers (rather than arrays).

Comment: As both `c_Digit` and `premis_numb` are arrays, it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Paul R i left it as char because it only takes in one letter or suppose to only take in one .... and i made the change for premis and c_digit thanks

Comment: It's better to use a string even if you only need one char, otherwise it's easy to get a white space character instead of the intended character. You can parse the string afterwards and remove any white space or other unwanted characters and just extract the character that you need.

Comment: @PaulR did that ..... but out of curiosity i am wondering why was it skipping the rea_type though.... :(

Comment: You'll often get white space left over from the previous input, so it's a good idea to take a more robust approach to user input.

Answer (score 0):

*You don't need to pass a reference of char[]*.  premin_num & c_Digit are the starting address of the char[]. Do like this

```
 scanf("%s",premis_numb);
 scanf("%s",c_Digit);
```

One possible reason your compiler is skipping input in `rea_type` scanf is because there was a newline entered by the user, `so if there's a stray newline in the input stream (from a previous entry, for example) the scanf call will consume it immediately & skip taking input.`

**Solution:**

***provide space before*** `%c`

```
scanf(" %s",&rea_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't skip reading the character, it reads the *newline* left in the input buffer after the last `scanf`.

This is simple to fix, by telling `scanf` to skip leading whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c", &rea_type);
```

Notice the space before the formatting code.

Comment: ahhh sorry the test variables arent entered in the right order .... just realize i changed the code order